# Ferromagnetic core with air gap

Tags: magnetics, ferrite, calculus

[image: Core]

```
N=200
I=N*8A
l=20cm=2*10^-1
d(delta)=1mm=10^-3
M=?
```

M=(B/μ)-H

How can I get the vector of magnetization? The relative permeability is not known. Everything I tried so far needs this value. There is no "shaking" of the magnetic field in the air gap.
Is this true Hm=-Ha (H magnet =-H gap) ?

Comment: Reluctance is length/(u*Area) and the total reluctance around the circuit is R_core+R_air, once you have the total reluctance you can work backwards to get the relative permeability. u = u_r*u_0, R_air = (air gap length)/(u_air*A_core) and R_core = (core length)/(u_core*A_core). That'll at least get you the relative permeability of the whole system.

Comment: I tried this way. What do you have in mind for "work backwards"?

Comment: The permeability ratio air/core is so small that only the gap distance plays the role. Like having a circuit, with one very low resitance variable with lentgh (core) and one very big resitance. No matter what low resitance is, you can calculate current only using the big resistance.

Comment: I assume your trying to find the relative effective permeability for the path around the whole core? By finding and summing the two reluctances (R_total = R_core+R_air), you can get the relative permeability by using the formula: u_r = (L_core+L_air)/(A_core\*R_total) That should give you the effective permeability for the whole thing. I'm assuming the permeability of the *core* is known? Or have I misunderstood what you meant by "the relative permeability is not known"? (most iron and ferrite cores are in the 1k-10k u_r range)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have enough information to calculate the H field or the flux in the gap.

You do know the available mmf (magneto motive force) which is 8amps * 200 turns = 1600 At.

The resulting H field is 1600/L, where L is the effective magnetic length.

Given that you have no information about the detailed geometry of the system (other than the lengths), you can assume that the effective air-equivalent magnetic length is 4*l = 800mm of iron, plus 1mm of air.

To write that as a single figure, we need the permeability of the iron. The effective length is then 800mm/ur_iron + 1mm.

One common option is to assume ur is infinite, which is sort of OK for small air-gaps. This air gap is quite large, and the difference between using 'typical' values of ur, which are in the 1k to 10k range, and infinity, is quite a substantial fraction.